# Can this matrix about the Kronecker product continue to be simplified?

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, kronecker-product

There is a $ML \times ML$ matrix expression based on the Kronecker product:
$$
\mathbf{J}=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{I}_L\otimes \left[ \begin{matrix}
 1&  0&  \cdots&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right]\\
 \mathbf{I}_L\otimes \left[ \begin{matrix}
 0&  1&  \cdots&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right]\\
 \vdots\\
 \mathbf{I}_L\otimes \left[ \begin{matrix}
 0&  0&  \cdots&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right]\\
\end{array} \right] 
$$
where $\mathbf{I}_L$ is a $L \times L$ identity matrix, $ \left[ 0,0,\cdots,1,0,\cdots,0,0 \right] $ is a $1 \times M$ vector with 1 in the $m$-th column and 0 in the rest.

I would like to know if this matrix $\mathbf{J}$ can be further simplified? So that I can make the calculation more efficient in MATLAB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can try with small matrices and you will see that there is a pattern, in that $J$ will be a permutation matrix. At that point you need to figure out the pattern of it. Should be doable. Perhaps there is an algebraic way which might be faster, not sure

Comment: @VanBaffo, Thank you for your suggestion, I constructed this matrix as a function of permutation, and I would like to make this permutation matrix more concise and computationally efficient.

Comment: What do you mean by more computationally efficient? What is the ultimate goal you would like to reach?

Comment: In MATLAB, matrix calculations tend to be the most efficient, but if they are performed in a loop (e.g., a for loop), it will make the calculations less efficient, so I'd like to reduce this J to the operation of matrices, rather than having to perform M loops to get this matrix.